# ImproperlyConfigured: Field name first_name is not valid for model CustomUser?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-allauth, django-rest-auth

help,
Registrations, login, logout is working perfectly but when I try the url

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/

it is showing me this error. Where am I wrong in which step of the program.

> ImproperlyConfigured: Field name first_name is not valid for model CustomUser?

## model.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from .managers import CustomUserManager

class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField(_('username'), max_length=100,unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    full_name = models.CharField(_("Full Name"), max_length=50, null=True)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField( auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, null=True)
    is_verified = models.BooleanField(_("Verified"), default=False)


    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    def has_perm(self,perm,obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(self,app_label):
        return True`from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_auth.registration.serializers import RegisterSerializer
```

## serializer.py

```
class RegisterSerializer(RegisterSerializer):
    full_name = serializers.CharField()
    date_of_birth = serializers.DateField()
    is_verified = serializers.BooleanField(read_only=True,default=False)


    def get_cleaned_data(self):
        super(RegisterSerializer, self).get_cleaned_data()
        return {
            'username': self.validated_data.get('username', ''),
            'password1': self.validated_data.get('password1', ''),
            'email': self.validated_data.get('email', ''),
            'date_of_birth': self.validated_data.get('date_of_birth', ''),
            'full_name': self.validated_data.get('full_name', ''),
            'is_verified': self.validated_data.get('is_verified', '')
        }
```

## setting.py

import os

```
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'b#7+#esnu76n3f$jb8sx52l*--r(ic2l-&=gmx*6zn!ced0ljy'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'rest_auth',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'rest_auth.registration',
    'users',
]
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.CustomUser'
ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
#ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'mandatory'
#ACCOUNT_CONFIRM_EMAIL_ON_GET = True
#ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_ANONYMOUS_REDIRECT_URL = '/?verification=1'
#sACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_AUTHENTICATED_REDIRECT_URL = '/?verification=1'

SITE_ID = 1
REST_AUTH_REGISTER_SERIALIZERS = {
    'REGISTER_SERIALIZER': 'users.serializers.RegisterSerializer',
}

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'customuser.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'customuser.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

**What's wrong?**

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You should run

```
python manage.py makemigrations user
```

Then

```
python manage.py migrate user
```

then restart your app

Comment: the  /user/  in  http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/ is django-rest-auth base url  /user[name='rest_user_details'] .